# React Toggle Button color attribute

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to change the color attribute for `ToggleButton` in React.

I'd like to to do something like
`<ToggleButton color='primary' />`

The `ToggleButton` API is not currently supporting this option. A workaround that I found was overriding the `MuiToggleButton` CSS class.

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
    overrides: {
        MuiToggleButton: {
            root: {
                color: 'rgba(50, 72, 86, 0.38)',
                '&$selected': {
                    backgroundColor: 'rgba(50, 72, 86, 0.12)',
                    color: 'rgba(50, 72, 86, 1)',
                    '&:hover': {
                        backgroundColor: 'rgba(50, 72, 86, 0.15)',
                    },
                },
            },
        },
    },
}
```

This solution overrides all the `ToggleButton` so it might be problematic in some situations.

Comment: It isn't clear to me what your question is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a custom Toggle component and apply the corresponding color from the theme

```js
import React from "react";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import ToggleButton from "@material-ui/lab/ToggleButton";
import ToggleButtonGroup from "@material-ui/lab/ToggleButtonGroup";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: (props) => {
    return {
      color: theme.palette[props.color].main
      // some other custom styles
    };
  }
}));

function MyToggleButton(props) {
  const { color, ...other } = props;
  const classes = useStyles({ color });
  return <ToggleButton classes={classes} {...other} />;
}

export default function CustomColorToggle() {
  const [color, setColor] = React.useState("primary");
  const handleColor = (e, value) => setColor(value);
  return (
    <ToggleButtonGroup
      onChange={handleColor}
      value={color}
      exclusive
      aria-label="text alignment"
    >
      <MyToggleButton color="primary" value="primary">
        Primary
      </MyToggleButton>
      <MyToggleButton color="secondary" value="secondary">
        Secondary
      </MyToggleButton>
    </ToggleButtonGroup>
  );
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/custom-color-toggle-7r0mf?file=/demo.js:0-1037

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thanks alot :)

Comment: @Marc-AndréJolicoeur if so, I'll appreciate you accept my answer